# Adding MetadataReference in Roslyn Vs Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

Tags: c#, roslyn

Roslyn version 1.2.* has a function called `MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference()` which takes the display name of the assembly and returns the appropriate `MetadataReference` object. For example I was able to add reference to various assemblies as follows:

```
Compilation compilation = Compilation.Create("HelloWorld")
                .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("mscorlib"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Linq"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Data.Linq"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Data"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Data.DataSetExtensions"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Xml"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Xml.Linq"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Core")
                //MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System.Core"),
                /*MetadataReference.CreateAssemblyReference("System")*/)
                .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
```

This however does not seem possible with the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis package (this is the latest package that one can install from Nuget). This package has a few functions inside `MetadataReference` - but they either require an Assembly or a file path.

Does that above mentioned simpler function exist in newer compiler packages?

Comment: No; you need to tell it where to load the assembly from.

Comment: Oh - meaning for an assembly like "System.Data.DataSetExtensions" would I have to specify the complete path like "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089" ? Is there an easy way to get this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can load the assembly with the CLR loader and find out where it was loaded from:

```
typeof(DataSetExtensions).Assembly.Location
```